# Active Record .includes and where query requires table name in where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

hoping someone can explain this.

I have

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :course_bookings, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

class CourseBooking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_plan

class CoursePlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_bookings, :dependent => :destroy
```

The query i am trying to do is

for a given student, find me all the course_bookings where their  course_plan code is equal to "ENG"

Also I want to eager load course_booking.course_plan
e.g.

```
  s = Student.first

  s.course_bookings.includes(:course_plan).where(course_plans:{code:'ENG'}).references(:course_plans).size
```

results in 1

where as

```
  s.course_bookings.includes(:course_plan).where(course_plan:{code:'ENG'}).references(:course_plans).size
```

i.e. removed the **s** in `.where(course_plan:{code:'ENG'})`

results in

**PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "course_plan"**

I don't understand why i need the **s** in the where clause.

I know the sql produced is

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "course_plans" ON "course_plans"."id" = "course_bookings"."course_plan_id" WHERE "course_bookings"."student_id" = $1 AND "course_plans"."code" = 'ENG'"
```

vs

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "course_plans" ON "course_plans"."id" = "course_bookings"."course_plan_id" WHERE "course_bookings"."student_id" = $1 AND "course_plan"."code" = 'ENG'"
```

i.e. difference is  `"course_plan"."code" = 'ENG'"` VS `"course_plans"."code" = 'ENG'"`

I would have thought Active Record smart enough to realise my belongs_to assoication is called course_plan?

Wondering am i doing this all wrong? or can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within the where() scope is closer to sql than to activerecord.  You could also write it directly as sql:

```
where("course_plans.code = 'ENG'")
```

The course_plans: key on the hash in the where scope is taken as the name of the table, not the name of the belongs_to association; hence the PG error - there is no table named 'course_plan'.